# New Pi3 came with pre loaded SD card no network icon

Tags: wireless

New Pi 3 and everything seems ok, but no network icon so I added one. (it is red exes when I click on it) It shows my wireless network and asks for a pre-shared key. My DSL wireless router has a ten digit numeric access code that works with every other wireless device I have. The input box on pi will not let me input numbers. The input box input is set on simple. Any ideas? I need to try and decide if the device is defective and send it back or not. Thanks

Comment: First, to get to a sane state, flash a recent Raspbian to you mSD card, regardless of what stale version has been delivered to you. You can use the Etcher flash tool from http://etcher.io that is easy to use and available for Windows, Linux, Os X. Also, what WLAN router do you have that comes preinstalled with a 10digit WPA passphrase? Can you please tell us your home address, so people can crack it in seconds and get into your network?

Comment: You don't have, by chance, an old WEP-only WLAN router because that's what the digit-based passphrase hints at? These WLAN access points are blocked in Raspbian, so you can't connect to it, because WEP is cracked in seconds. You may have alteady a lot of guests in your WEP network then.